# Phonegap index.js not entering $(function(){})

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

This only happens on the device, not in the simulator. I can get as far as the 1st alert which leads me to believe it's not a html issue (very open to correction on this of course...). In the weinre debugger, I tried copying and pasting the $(document).on function but it said $(document) was null. This was working fine yesterday evening until i accidentally opened the file with libre office instead of notepad++. Notepad++ shows the line breaks as `CR CF`, could that have something to do with it?

Edit: I copied the contents of index.html to a notepad file and saved it as html in order to get rid of any hidden formatting. I've also added jQuery as the first script in index.html.

Finally, if I look at the elements in the weinre debugger, I can see index.html.

**jQuery(document) gives me `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` so something seems to be wrong with jquery...**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

The paths are correct

**Answer** ahem... my bat script to package the contents of bin/debug/ only packed the files and not the folders, so no js folder went into the zip...

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
window.PhotoScan = window.PhotoScan || {};

alert("we can get this far");


$(function () {

    alert("how do we not get to here???!!!!!");

    $(document).on("deviceready", function () {
        alert("index #5");
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        if(window.devextremeaddon) {
            window.devextremeaddon.setup();
        }
        $(document).on("backbutton", function () {
            DevExpress.processHardwareBackButton();
        });
    });

    function onNavigatingBack(e) {
        if (e.isHardwareButton && !PhotoScan.app.canBack()) {
            e.cancel = true;
            alert("index #6");
            exitApp();
        }
    }

    function exitApp() {
        switch (DevExpress.devices.real().platform) {
            case "android":
                navigator.app.exitApp();
                break;
            case "win8":
                window.external.Notify("DevExpress.ExitApp");
                break;
        }
    }

    alert("index #7");
    PhotoScan.app = new DevExpress.framework.html.HtmlApplication({
        namespace: PhotoScan,
        layoutSet: DevExpress.framework.html.layoutSets[PhotoScan.config.layoutSet],
        navigation: PhotoScan.config.navigation,
        commandMapping: PhotoScan.config.commandMapping
    });

    alert("index #8");

    PhotoScan.app.router.register(":view/:id", { view: "home", id: undefined });
    PhotoScan.app.on("navigatingBack", onNavigatingBack);

    PhotoScan.app.navigate();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you have gone wrong, but typically i just wrap my bootstrap code inside the device ready. As i typically create a db schema first anyways.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  alert("index #5");
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    if(window.devextremeaddon) {
        window.devextremeaddon.setup();
    }
    $(document).on("backbutton", function () {
        DevExpress.processHardwareBackButton();
    });
 });

 // ... your other functions here
```

If you want to keep them off global scope, can just wrap them in a self executing function:

```
(function() {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {});
})();
```

I haven't used document ready in cordova apps, as i just have the js scripts load at the bottom. Then i load most content through handle bar templates and javascript.

**Edit**

As per the comments, you need to make sure that each time you add a new file or make a change to files in a cordova project, it must be rebuilt:

```
 cordova run ios --device
 cordova run android
```

Comment: I've edited my answer. After further research it turns out jQuery doesn't seem to be loading

Comment: I imagine it's all under the www folder? Be sure it's getting copied into the build: `platforms/android/assets/www` `platforms/ios/www/`. Remember that each time you change anything in www, you need to do a new build. `cordova run android` or `cordova run ios` :)

Comment: Updated existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

@rory,

you wrote `$(function(){})`
This is NOT a good way to do things. If your function fails, for whatever reason, your program will NOT work.

Did you intend to do this?

Jesse

Comment: this comes from the framework code from DevExtreme/PhoneJS

Comment: Just because someone wrote it does not make it a good design. This would NOT make it on my list for review. IMO, this is a framework heading for disaster. Best of Luck.